# C++ Template Method Overloading and Class Access with Polymorphism

Tags: c++, templates, visual-studio-2017, polymorphism, overloading

I noticed something which I think is pretty interesting behaviour.

Consider the following example code which I tried to keep as generic as possible:

```
class Base
{
public:
  virtual void func() {}
};

class Subclass : public Base
{
public:
  void func() {}
};

class ApplyingClass
{
public:
  static void callFunc(Base& base) { base.func(); }
private:
  template <class T>
  static void callFunc(T& t) { t.func(); }
};

int main()
{
  Subclass s;
  Base& b = s;

  // Error: ApplyingClass::callFunc(T& t) with T=Subclass is private.
  ApplyingClass::callFunc(s);

  // works
  ApplyingClass::callFunc(b);

  return 0;
}
```

It seems that inside main(), due to the template method being present, the compiler sees the template "ApplyingClass::callFunc(T& t)" as the right fit for the function call "ApplyingClass::callFunc(s)" and throws an Error since the method is not accessible from outside it's class.

This seems logical, yet I expected the compiler to still go and try to use "ApplyingClass::callFunc(Base& base)" since the method signature fits and this is the only *accessible* fitting method.

To take my point a bit further; if I were to remove the private template method from ApplyingClass, both function calls inside main() would be valid.

My question now is whether this is part of the C++ specification or if this is compiler specific behaviour (this was tested using the Visual Studio 2017 ver 15.5.7 compiler).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's valid C++ to emit an error here.

See [class.member.lookup]:

> If the name of an overloaded function is unambiguously found, **overload resolution  also takes place before
>   access control**.

So the appropriate overload is selected first  (the template), and then access control happens, which causes a compiler error.

Comment: I see, this is kind of what I suspected. Too bad since this makes the use of polymorphism while retaining this pattern much more of a hassle. Then again there are better approaches for this. Thanks for pointing out the relevant clause in the C++ standard.

Comment: Often if I write a private version of a public function, I append "helper" to the private function name.

Comment: Yeah renaming the private method was also what I ended up doing. Usually I try to avoid renaming functions where overloading is the more apparent thing to do though.